# Error install matplotlib in virtual environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv, zsh

Trying to install `matplotlib` in a virtual environment. When running `pip install matplotlib` I get the following error:

```
zsh: /Users/username/Desktop/tensorflow_tutorials/.venv/bin/pip: bad interpreter:
/Users/username/Desktop/tensorflow/.venv/bin/python3: no such file or directory
```

`tensorflow_tutorials` is the directory in which I have created the virtual environment in.

I have tried `pip3 install matplotlib` and get the following message:

```
zsh: /Users/username/Desktop/tensorflow_tutorials/.venv/bin/pip3: bad interpreter: /Users/username/Desktop/tensorflow/.venv/bin/python3: no such file or directory
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
```

I have tried running `source ./.venv/bin/activate` before `pip install` but does not work either.